# Correct meaning of "Straight Over"

Tags: meaning

I have a sentence:

> You must drive to headington roundabout where you go **straight over** and make your way to Newbury.

Does it mean where you go **straight through(something)**? (because one meaning of over is through)

Comment: To me, that would be to maintain your cardinal direction, i.e. to proceed straight, in effect, as though the roundabout hadn't been there, once you are out of it.  (Drive through the roundabout properly, of course.  :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight over means you go around the roundabout, but exit it travelling in the same direction at which you entered it.

In this case you go *straight over* the headington roundabout.

Almost as if you are *driving straight over* the roundabout as if it didn't exist, although of course you are not, you are driving around the roundabout just exiting it opposite the point at which you entered it.

For example here's a little diagram I made to illustrate:

[image]